# Is there a way to avoid definition of a method with a certain name?

Tags: ruby, methods

Is there a way to avoid (raise an error when it is attempted) definition of a method with a certain name, for example `Foo#bar`? (A usecase would be when `Foo#bar` is already defined, and I want to avoid that method being overridden, but that is irrelevant to the question.) I am assuming something like:

```
class Foo
  prohibit_definition :bar
end

...
# Later in some code

class Foo
  def bar
    ...
  end
end
# => Error: `Foo#bar' cannot be defined
```

Comment: I'd bet money on "can't be done".

Comment: @millimoose I'd take that bet.

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci You'll have to make do with ten rep points instead of money.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can catch the callback in `method_added(`) of `Module` class and check the method name and delete the added method if it does not meet your criteria. Then you can raise an error.

Not you want exactly but close enough I think.

```
class Class
  def method_added(method_name)
    if method_name == :bar
        remove_method :bar
        puts "#{method_name} cannot be added to #{self}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you got the idea. And Shawn Balestracci gave the implementation of that.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Class
  def method_added(method_name)
    raise "So sad, you can't add" if method_name == :bad
  end
end

class Foo
  def bad
    puts "Oh yeah!"
  end
end

#irb> RuntimeError: So sad, you can't add
#   from (irb):3:in `method_added'
#   from (irb):7
```

Comment: you raise an error but the method is added actually. Or am i mistaken ?

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi  I was able to call Foo.new.bad in 1.8.7 from IRB so in some cases it does get added.  It depends on how harsh you want to be,  if you really wanted to cause punishment you could undef_method instead.